# How to iterate through multiple file extension without caring about case sensitivity?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I've seen various topics on how to iterate through multiple file extensions but in most case, the list is defined.

example:

```
for file in ${arg}/**/*.{txt,h,py}
do
    ....
done
```

As can be seen, `.TXT` files would be ignored. And sadly, the guy who answered it says it only works for bash4. but my setup uses bash3.x.

Any ideas on how it can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate through a list of files with spaces that is sorted (case insensitive)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146039/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-files-with-spaces-that-is-sorted-case-insensit)

Comment: Use the `find` command to select the files on any depth, then its `-exec` option to do something on them. No need to use bash.

Comment: @Tejas, that is not the same question at all.

Comment: Could you please [edit] and clarify your question? It does indeed seem very similar to your previous one. What are you actually trying to achieve? What would `${arg}` be here? Do you need recursion? What kind of directory structure would you have? What guy answered it? What did this guy answer? You say that in most cases the list is defined, is it defined in your case?

Answer (score 7):

In `bash` you can set `nocaseglob`:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob

for file in "$arg"/**/*.{txt,h,py}
do
  ....
done

shopt -u nocaseglob
```

`noclaseglob` is fine to use in any `bash` since 2.01, however `**` requires `bash` 4.0 or later (and it follows symlinks up to `bash` 4.3 where it was fixed). Note the correction to quote `$arg` since there will be problems if this contains spaces or glob characters.

Without using `**` you can do something like:

```
find "$arg" \( -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.h' -o -iname '*.py' \) -exec bash -c '
  for file; do
    ...
  done' bash {} +
```

This will find all the files you are looking for and pass them as separate arguments to a new bash instance, which will then loop through them. If your per file operation is a single command, you can probably skip the new bash instance and use the command directly.

#### Update

As per Stephane's comments below, the POSIX compatible solution is:

```
find "$arg" \( -name '*.[tT][xX][tT]' -o -name '*.[hH]' -o -name '*.[pP][yY]' \) \
  -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    ...
  done' sh {} +
```

Comment: `**` appeared in bash 4 (borrowed from ksh93, itself borrowing it with differences from zsh). The following of symlinks was fixed in 4.3. You need `shopt -s globstar` for it.

Comment: Note that `-iname` is not standard. You also need braces as -a has precedence over -o and so only `.py` files will be processed. Also note that `find` will include hidden files (and descend into hidden dirs) while `**/` will not by default.

Answer (score 7):

Use `zsh` instead:

```
setopt extendedglob
for f ($arg/**/*.(#i)(txt|h|py)(N.)) {
  ...
}
```

- `**/`: any level of subdirectories
- `(#i)` is to turn case insensitive matching on for the rest of the glob (like `~(i)` in `ksh93`).
- `(N.)` is the glob qualifier. `N` is to not return an error if there's no matching file and `.` to select regular files only (the equivalent of `find`'s `-type f`)). You could add a `D` in there to also match dot (hidden) files and descend into hidden dirs (like `find` would be default).

Comment: While your answer looks factually correct, it would be good to elaborate it a little more on how it works. I know it's an old answer, but this question got bumped to the front page because of another answer.

Comment: @Centimane, see if the edit makes it any clearer.

Comment: Looks more clear to me, have an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

What about a simple:

```
for file in "$(ls -1 | grep -iE '\.txt|\.py|\.h')";
do
  ....
done
```

Another simple option is:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.txt'; find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.py'; find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.h';
```

You can wrap find in $() parentheses in bash to have the list.

Comment: Care to comment downvotes? It could a way to learn something.

Comment: the problem is `grep -iE '.txt|.py|.h'`, you have to escape the `.` as it will match any char. `grep -iE '\.txt|\.py|\.h'`